# Firebase is login user multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

[image: Show of weird behavior]

This happens everytime I hit the login button.

First login: callback shows 2 logins

First logout

Second login: callback shows 4 logins

Second logout

Third login: callback now shows 5 logins in row

etc.

This is my login function:

```
$scope.userLogin = function(user){
        $scope.userLoginEmail = user.email;
        $scope.userLoginPassword = user.password;

        $scope.authUser().login('password', {
            email: $scope.userLoginEmail,
            password: $scope.userLoginPassword
        });
        $scope.loginModalHide();
        user.email = '';
        user.password = '';
    };
```

My question is simple. Why is this happening? Sometimes even if I hit logout, login is called automatically.

Comment: The code sample you've provided above does not reproduce the error you've described. Please provide a short code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: @Kato So there is my AuthCtrl and Factory:

http://jsfiddle.net/D9v7j/

Comment: That code [still doesn't run](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or produce the condition you've described :(

Comment: @Kato I can't run whole code because I use Appgyver Steroids and code just don't run in jsfiddle. I provided whole Auth controller and I think there is everything about login function. I've updated it and provide login modal. The point is, function is just copied from Firebase page.

Comment: @Kato There is whole app on Github: https://github.com/Jirka1111/smoneybox/tree/master/www

Comment: @Kato I found that how many times I click on logout so many times +1 after another login it writes me to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a looking at your `AuthCtrl` it seems that you're using FirebaseSimpleLogin without the AngularFire bindings. You'll run into issues with the `$digest` loop this way. One of the benefits of using AngularFire is that it places nice with `$digest` loop so we don't have to worry about applying scope or setting timeouts.

AngularFire provides a `$firebaseSimpleLogin` binding. When a user logs in and out an event is fired off on `$rootScope`.

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
  var simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase('<your-firebase>'));

  $scope.user = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  $scope.login = function() {
    simpleLogin.$login('password', {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    });
  };

  $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function(e, user) {
    // handler post login event
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout', function(e, user) {
    // handler post logout event
  });

});
```

I usually encapsulate the `$firebaseSimpleLogin` binding within a factory. You can check out an demo example on Plunker here:

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/M0UJmm?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try implement this and learn Angular better. Still have issues with understanding factories etc. Thanks again! By the way, great simple graphic on your Plunker demo ;)